# How do you treat hashes in arrays properly?

Tags: perl

I've got an array of hashes:

```
my @questions = (
    {"Why do you study here?" => "bla"},
    {"What are your hobbies?" => "blabla"});
```

And I try to loop through it:

```
foreach (@questions) {
    my $key = (keys $_)[0];
    $content .= "\\section{$key}\n\n$_{$key}\n\n";
}
```

giving me

> Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at
>   convert.pl line 44.

Where does the error come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Gilles already explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22045772/176646) how to use your current data structure, but I would recommend that you use a different data structure altogether: a simple hash.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my %answers = (
    "Why do you study here?" => "bla",
    "What are your hobbies?" => "blabla"
);

while (my ($question, $answer) = each %answers) {
    say "Question: $question";
    say "Answer: $answer";
}
```

#### Output:

```
Question: Why do you study here?
Answer: bla
Question: What are your hobbies?
Answer: blabla
```

I find this easier to work with than an array of hashes, each of which only contains a single key/value pair.

If you want to iterate through the hash in a certain (non-sorted) order, there are a couple of options. The simplistic solution is to maintain an array of keys in the order you want to access them:

```
# In the order you want to access them
my @questions = ("What are your hobbies?", "Why do you study here?");

my %answers;
@answers{@questions} = ("blabla", "bla");

foreach my $question (@questions) {
    say "Question: $question";
    say "Answer: $answers{$question}";
}
```

#### Output:

```
Question: What are your hobbies?
Answer: blabla
Question: Why do you study here?
Answer: bla
```

Another option is to use [Tie::IxHash](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::IxHash) (or the faster XS module [Tie::Hash::Indexed](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::Hash::Indexed)) to access keys in insertion order:

```
use Tie::IxHash;

tie my %answers, "Tie::IxHash";

%answers = (
    "Why do you study here?" => "bla",
    "What are your hobbies?" => "blabla"
);

while (my ($question, $answer) = each %answers) {
    say "Question: $question";
    say "Answer: $answer";
}
```

#### Output:

```
Question: Why do you study here?
Answer: bla
Question: What are your hobbies?
Answer: blabla
```

Comment: +1 for correctly guessing what I was aiming at with the structure - namely, defining an arbitrary, but fixed order - and providing a workaround. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

`$_{$key}` looks up `$key` in the hash variable `%_`. The sigil `$` at the beginning indicates that the type of the result is a scalar. It's the syntactic construct `VAR{KEY}` that determines that `VAR` must be a hash. Although `$_` and `%_` use the same symbol as a name, the different sigils make them unrelated variables.

You need to dereference the hash reference `$_` into the underlying hash. The syntax for this is `$_->{$key}` or `${$_}{$key}`.

See the [reference tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for a more general presentation of the topic.

Answer (score 2):

The elements of `@questions` are **references to hash**, not hashes. Therefore, you should use them like this:

```
foreach (@questions) {
    my $key = (keys %$_)[0];
    print "\\section{$key}\n\n$_->{$key}\n\n";
}
```

See [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) for how to create and use reference.